# Spring Autowiring WebServiceProvider

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws, autowired

Using "classic" Jax-WS endpoints, I'm trying to autowire my business logic (service) class into the web services.  I've come across posts saying all that's required is to extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport... I've done this to no avail.  One key difference is that I'm using the @WebServiceProvider annotation instead of @WebService.  Is there a problem using this with WebServiceProvider?

Here's my web service:

```
@WebServiceProvider
@ServiceMode(value=javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
public class InventoryAddChangeImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements Provider<Source> {

@Autowired
private MyService service;

@Override
public Source invoke(Source request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

And my service class:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements Service {

@Override
public void doWork() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
}
```

When I breakpoint on invoke of the web service, the service property is null.

Here's the only entries in my appContext:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.somewhere.service.myservices,com.somewhere.ws.server"/>
```

What am I missing?  Has anyone got this same design to work?
I can wrap these in a Spring Web Service endpoint instead, and then autowiring would work, but everyone who will maintain this is familiar with the basic Jax-WS endpoint configuration.

Comment: I don't know Jax-WS at all, but does Spring have any reason to generate a bean of type `InventoryAddChangeImpl` in your context? If no, then how will it autowire anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't - in fact it is definitely not maintained by the Spring container but rather the JAX-WS runtime.  The SpringBeanAutowiringSupport [link]http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html is (I believe) meant to be a way around this.  See the notes in the class description for it describing use with JAX-WS endpoints.